# WebJob QueueTrigger TimeoutException: The operation 'GetMessages' did not complete in '00:02:00'

Tags: .net, azure, azure-webjobs

A bit related to [my issue 60304305](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60304305/azure-webjobs-catch-error-to-prevent-host-failure)... My Azure webJob application handles multiple queues, but they don't generate high traffic. Still, the app will encounter a Timeout Exception from time to time, and it's almost impossible to reproduce the error, but I had some success when breaking at a Breakpoint inside a Queue function and leave it for a while.

```
System.TimeoutException
  HResult=0x********
  Message=The operation 'GetMessages' with id '********-****-****-****-************' did not complete in '00:02:00'.
  Source=Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.TimeoutHandler.<ExecuteWithTimeout>d__1`1.MoveNext() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\TimeoutHandler.cs:line 30
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.WebJobsExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<OnUnhandledExceptionAsync>b__0() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Timers\WebJobsExceptionHandler.cs:line 54
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.TimeoutHandler.ExecuteWithTimeout<T>(string, string, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.IWebJobsExceptionHandler, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>>) in TimeoutHandler.cs
    Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.WebJobsExceptionHandler.OnUnhandledExceptionAsync.AnonymousMethod__0() in WebJobsExceptionHandler.cs
    System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object)
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, object, bool)
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, object, bool)
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, object)
    System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Interestingly, the namespace appears to be "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.**Timers**" but I'm not using any timers, only queues. Also, the Timeout of '00:02:00' is long. And the functions could run for hours but then fail at some time. The big problems here are:

1. The exceptions appears "out of nowhere", it cannot be catched or gracefully handled, or at least I don't know how, so any help is appreciated
2. No further information available, I'd like to know which Queue (is it always the same? etc.)

I tried updating the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to a high number as advised [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/755) with no success, tried multiple different Queue settings (`BatchSize`, `MaxDequeueCount` etc. going from low to high numbers, also no success etc.) I'm tired of trying things, I need to find more information but I don't know how.

#### Versions:

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.14
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions 3.0.6
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 3.0.10
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage 3.0.14

Comment: Could you share you function code so I could have a test?

Comment: Same thing using an Azure Function with Python runtime. What is interesting is this is running *synchronous* Python code, yet the Azure log error says: `"The operation 'GetMessageAsync' with id '<GUID-HERE>' did not complete in '00:03:00'."`

Answer (score 2):

I also have those weird errors, and I don't know where they come from either. However, I found a way to handle them: when the host is shutting down, the `CancellationToken` is cancelled and you can monitor its cancellation via the [`Register` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-register-callbacks-for-cancellation-requests).

For example:

```cs
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public async Task ProcessMyQueueMessageAsync(
    [QueueTrigger("myqueue")] MyQueueMessage payload,
    ExecutionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    token.Register(async () =>
    {
        // your code to handle such an error, can be an async function
    });
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, thank you. I will not be able to try this though, because we got rid of the issues, but using a rather radical way: We ported our app to use the Azure Service Bus Queue instead. Now having a `[ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue")]` no issues appear, but the migration has it's own caveats :)

Comment: That's interesting, I might try that as well :)